# Audio hosting platform / Server-side software

Tags: audio, streaming, hosting, video-streaming, soundcloud

I'm looking for somewhat for audio which is like **Kewego** or **Dailymotion Cloud** to video.

I'm looking for a good service to:

- Encode user-uploaded audio files in predefined qualities
- Stream it on demand in a more or less customisable player.

--

The goal is to run my own audio hosting platform, a bit like **Soundcloud**.

I'm open to all kinds of solutions, but I would prefer a cloud hosting with good API to interface it in a white label way. But if you know good server-side software, I could also use that...

---

**Edit:**

The bounty is now opened for 7 days and no answers: if you have any clues for me to achieve my platform, I'm interested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**API based encoder ->** [www.zencoder.com](http://www.zencoder.com)

**Player ->** If you are looking for something as robust as soundcloud, you are going to have to write that yourself. Otherwise something like jplayer could work. http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demos/

**Home Baked ->** A combination of [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) + [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com) would give you a nice 1 - 2 punch for encoding / adaptive bitrate delivery. (Wowza doesn't support VOD transcoding with their "Transcode AddOn" yet, otherwise you would be able to use JUST wowza). They also have a deal with Amazon for daily instances if you just want to try it out.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your answer. It's exactly the pointers I need. For the streaming part, do you know any API based provider ? Where can I send my files after zencoder has done its job ?

Comment: Well, correct me if I am wrong, but now you are just asking how to host files. You don't need a streaming server to deliver your typical .mp3 "stream" as these are pretty tiny files. Any CDN fronted webhost would work. 


Zencoder is hosted on Amazon, so for best "file-transfer-chi", you could spin up your own EC2 host and front it with cloudfront.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question wasn't "how to host my files" but rather "what is the SaaS equivalent of Wowza", taking into account that you headed me to this solution. But I understand your answer, it's OK. Thank you again.

Comment: Ahhhh, I think I get where you're coming from. You might be able to use something like brightcove for the player/hosting.

Comment: Thanks! Brightcove audio seems to be still in beta but this is a good starting point for me.